# How can I use wherejsoncontains when table column has array of objects with same keys and different values laravel php

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

Am trying to get check whether the data with condition exists in the column which is in json format as below.

Am having 2 columns id,test_data

In test_data column it has below jsonvalue

> {"test_info":[{"type":"text","name":'sam',"contact":9839383333,"applicant":1,"email":sam93@gmail.com,"address":"newyork"},
>   {"type":"textarea","name":'john',"contact":383839283,"applicant":0,"email":"john33@gmail.com","address":"california"}]}

Am trying to check where the data with name='sam' and type='text'exists in data or not. Have tried below once but its not working for the array of objects

```
TestData::select('id')->WhereJsonContains('test_data->test_info->type', ["text"]);
```

but the above one doesnot work as the column contains array of objects. how can I check whether the data is present or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
test_data->test_info->type
```

with

```
test_info[0]['type']
```

Comment: some times the required data may be present in second object then I can't Keep test_info[1]['type']. it should be dynamic.

Comment: Ok, just make this `$data = TestData::select('id')->WhereJsonContains('test_data->test_info->type', ["text"])->first();`

Comment: You can then call it like ` $data['type']`